# Auto-enable fic-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367611/emacs-highlighting-todo-only-in-comments) I got to know `fic-mode` which highlights TODOs and such in `c++` mode of `emacs`. However I couldn't make it auto-enabled; that is, I want it to be enabled as soon as I open a `.cpp` file. In my `.emacs` file I have:

```
(require 'fic-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'turn-on-fic-mode)
```

as recommended in the `fic-mode.el`. This doesn't do the trick. In order to enable the minor mode, I have to hit `M-x fic-mode RET` and then `M-x font-lock-fontify-buffer`. Can it be automated?

Answer (score 0):

I see its working properly in my emacs. It may be with your .emacs. how about calling like this(I dont think it make any difference.)

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook '(lambda () (fic-mode 1)))
```

its good to turn on debugger to see any errors. `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`. and open a cpp file.

Comment: Changing the `.emacs` didn't make a difference. Nothing popped up when the debugger was enabled. Problem is still there :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: does this turned on `emacs -Q foo.cpp -l /path/to/fic-mode.el -f turn-on-fic-mode` which version of emacs you are using?

Comment: Yes, the above turns on the mode. But, I'm using `Aquamacs`, and I cannot (for some unclear reason) do something similar. The version I have is 2.2 with emacs 23.3.1.